# How do I replace all WOrds with FAlse SEcond LEtter Capitalization in lots of Word documents?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, wildcards

I need to mass-correct large amounts of documents in German. I need to handle several hundred pages of text. I have written a macro to do mass find-and-replace operations on common spelling mistakes.

I need to find a way to correct the common typing ERror where the SEcond CHaracter is CApitalized ALthough it Should Not Be.

Is there a wild card search I can use to replace all occurrences of the mis-capitalized second character in a word with the lower-case counterpart?

Could this wildcard account for the fact that abbreviations should not be changed?

I suppose one could pull something like this off with RegEx. I'd also be willing to use a third party tool or an editor with this macro capability.

A web search did not do much good, I cannot seem to find the correct combination of search terms.

---

Example:

- *Before*: This is a TExt with FAlse CApitalization. The company ABC should not be affected, nor should US. And: TGIF.
- *After*: This is a Text with False Capitalization. The company ABC should not be affected, nor should US. And: TGIF

---

Excuse my frequent edits, but after some head-scratching and reading the Word manual I managed to create a wild card that would find a reasonably large subset of misspelled  words.

<[A-Z][A-Z][a-z][a-z]

It will find words like CApital and SMall but not UPS or HBO (not affiliated). Unfortunately, the replace field does not handle Regex. I am still looking for a method that will replace the misbehaving word with the correct spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd party tool called [TextPipe](http://www.datamystic.com/textpipe.html) (not affiliated) will let me do just what I need. I have managed to create a filtre after some tweaking. Beware, Windows only and nothing for the faint-of-heart (I haven't seen any GUI this ugly recently, and it's developer-oriented, so expect a steep learning curve). It is rather powerful, though.

I suppose something like this could also be pulled off for free with a VBA or RegEx script - of the sort:

```
1. Find all words that match these criteria
2. Convert all these words to uppercasefirst (uncapitalize them, after that recapitalize)
```

Feel free to disagree and provide a better solution or a freeware.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the handling of acronyms but Word 2007 (and potentially earlier) has a way to cycle through the main types of capitalization.

Select a block of text then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

This will cycle through the following:

- First letter capitalized
- Every Word Capitalized
- all words lower case

As I mentioned I do not know how well this deals with acronyms though.

Comment: It still works in Word 2010, I know about this. But there are hundreds of pages of text and it is just impractical that I do them all by hand.